# Computing relationship gaps using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, algorithm, graph-theory

Suppose I have a company whose reporting relationships are given by:

```
ref_pd = pd.DataFrame({'employee':['a','b','c','d','e','f'],'supervisor':['c','c','d','f','f',None]})
```

e.g.

- a and b report to c, who reports to d, who reports to f
- e also reports to f
- f is the head and reports to no one

Is there a (clever) way to use

- `ref_pd`
- I know a priori that there are at most 4 "layers" to the company (f is layer 1, d and e are layer 2, c is layer 3, a and b are layer 4)

to compute the last column of:

```
gap_pd = pd.DataFrame({'supervisor':['d','d','d','d','d','d'],'employee':['a','b','c','d','e','f'],'gap':[2,2,1,0,None,None]})
```

The logic of this last column is like this: with the supervisor = d for each row

- if the employee = d, then that is also the supervisor, so there is no gap, so gap = 0
- c reports directly to d, so gap = 1
- a and b report to c, who reports to d, so gap = 2
- neither e nor f (eventually) reports to d, so gap is Null

The only thing I can think of is feeding `ref_pd` to a directed graph then computing path lengths but I struggle for a graph-less (and hopefully pure pandas) solution.

Comment: Why don't you want to have a graph solution? Using pandas will require to loop anyway, at least as many times as there are hierarchy levels. So I imagine more complex code for a non-vectorial solution.

Comment: @mozway I have seen clever things people can do via merge, so while I personally struggled for a pure pandas solution, I thought I would ask here to see if the forum would have one. My other concern is that a graph-based solution may be slow when I scale the problem up (the company has hundreds of thousands of employees).

Comment: You can `merge`/`map`, but you'll have to follow the hierarchy path, meaning looping/iterating at some point

Comment: I had a quick look, why is the supervisor `d` in the output while `f` is the supervisor of `d`? I'd expect `f` to end up as supervisor. Or is `d` a query?

Comment: @mozway d is a query. And since d isn’t actually a supervisor if f (direct or otherwise), gap returns blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph of the hierarchy:

[image: graph]

If is possible using iterative `merge`s, but quite impractical:

```
target = 'd'

# set up containers
counts = pd.Series(index=ref_pd2['employee'], dtype=int)
valid = pd.Series(False, index=ref_pd['employee'])

# set up initial df2 for iterative merging
df2 = ref_pd.rename(columns={'employee': 'origin', 'supervisor': 'employee'})

# identify origin == target
valid[target] = True
counts[target] = 0

while df2['employee'].notna().any(): # or: for _ in range(4):
    # increment count for non valid items
    idx = valid[~valid].index
    counts[idx] = counts[idx].add(1, fill_value=0)
    
    # if we reached supervisor == target, set valid
    m2 = df2['employee'].eq(target)
    valid[df2.loc[m2, 'origin']] = True
    
    # update df2
    df2 = (df2.merge(ref_pd2, how='left')
          .drop(columns='employee')
          .rename(columns={'supervisor': 'employee'})
      )

# set invalid items to NA
counts[~valid] = pd.NA

# craft output
gap_pd = pd.DataFrame({'supervisor': target,
                       'employee': ref_pd['employee'],
                       'gap': ref_pd['employee'].map(counts),
                       })
```

output:

```
  supervisor employee  gap
0          d        a  2.0
1          d        b  2.0
2          d        c  1.0
3          d        d  0.0
4          d        e  NaN
5          d        f  NaN
```

In comparison, a [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) solution is much more explicit:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(ref_pd.dropna(),
                            source='supervisor', target='employee',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

target = 'd'

gap_pd = ref_pd.assign(supervisor=target)

gap_pd['gap'] = [nx.shortest_path_length(G, target, n)
                 if target in nx.ancestors(G, n) or n==target else pd.NA
                 for n in ref_pd['employee']]
```

output:

```
  employee supervisor   gap
0        a          d     2
1        b          d     2
2        c          d     1
3        d          d     0
4        e          d  <NA>
5        f          d  <NA>
```

Comment: I can confirm my worry about scaling has been unnecessary thus far. Your graph solution works beautifully.